# Exclude post from query based keyword in title

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a standard query that shows posts based on the number of views.

```
<?php $cat_id='-8';//the category ID
$limit = get_option('posts_per_page');
query_posts(array(
'showposts'=>32,'more' => $more = 0,
'v_sortby'  => 'views',
'v_orderby' => 'DESC',
'v_outtype' => 'content',
'v_timespan' => 'total',
'paged' => $paged
)); ?>              
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

However, I would like to exclude all posts that have the word "metal" in the title.

I did some searching and I found code that might accomplish this but I'm not sure how to apply it to the query?

```
if(strpos(get_the_title(), 'metal') === false) {
    // Title does not contain metal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query array looks like holding a query parameter.
I am not sure which parameter comes last before the 'order by' and limit statements. But by assuming v_timespan is the last condition and the values are used directly(without filtering) I recommend changing it (without messing with the actual query string - which is not shown your code) to:

```
array(
'showposts'=>32,'more' => $more = 0,
'v_sortby'  => 'views',
'v_orderby' => 'DESC',
'v_outtype' => 'content',
'v_timespan' => "total and title not like '%metal%'";
'paged' => $paged
))
```

Comment: Unfortunately the above code does not yield anything. But your code looks like an SQL query. Above is just a regular wordpress query and then loop.